# When should we use a custom deleter instead of the default deleter in a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, oop, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I couldn't understand, if there is already a default deleter in `unique_ptr`, then what is the need of using a custom deleter?

Could anyone explain this by giving a simple example?

Comment: It can be used e.g. when you manage the memory yourself "manually", or when you want the deleter to do something other than the default like closing a file (if relevant for the resource you are trying to manage).

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` can be used for almost any RAII task not just heap allocated memory.  If, for example, you use it with a resource handle it would need to know how to delete/clean-up the resource.

Comment: In case you want to do something else than `new/delete`. `fopen/fclose` for file management, or some other resource management. IIRC `LibGuard` uses `unique_ptr` custom deleters for releasing mutexes.

Comment: It is also handy when you have preallocated pool of some resources, so you request resource from this pool and deleter will return it to the pool.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of using `std::unique_ptr` to manage an old C style `FILE*` in [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) style.

The deleter will close the file automatically when the `std::unique_ptr` will attempt to release the managed resource.

This is useful e.g. if you have some legacy code using `FILE*` file(s) and you would like to avoid manually managing closing them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct FileDeleter
{
    void operator()(FILE* pFile)
    {
        if (pFile)
        {
            std::cout << "closing file ...\n";
            fclose(pFile);
        }
    }
};

using FileUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<FILE, FileDeleter>;

int main()
{
    {
        // Getting a FILE* from legacy code:
        FILE* pFile = nullptr;
        std::cout << "opening file ...\n";
        auto err = fopen_s(&pFile, "aaa.txt", "r");
        if (err != 0)
        {
            // Handle error ...
            return -1;
        }
        
        // New C++ code:
        FileUniquePtr filePtr{ pFile };
        // Do something with the file via filePtr ...

    } // Here filePtr goes out of scope and the deleter will be called and close the file automatically.
}
```

Output:

```
opening file ...
closing file ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I use custom deletes to quickly wrap C-API, for example to help me with OpenSSL:

```
namespace helper {
template<typename T>
struct Deleter;

template<>
struct Deleter<::BIO>
{
    void operator()(::BIO* p) const
    {
        // result used during debugging
        [[maybe_unused]] auto result = BIO_free(p);
    }
};

template<>
struct Deleter<::X509>
{
    void operator()(::X509* p) const
    {
        X509_free(p);
    }
};

template<>
struct Deleter<::PKCS12>
{
    void operator()(::PKCS12* p) const
    {
        PKCS12_free(p);
    }
};

template<>
struct Deleter<::EVP_PKEY>
{
    void operator()(::EVP_PKEY* p) const
    {
        EVP_PKEY_free(p);
    }
};

template<>
struct Deleter<STACK_OF(X509)>
{
    void operator()(STACK_OF(X509) * p) const
    {
        sk_X509_pop_free(p, X509_free);
    }
};

template<>
struct Deleter<STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME)>
{
    void operator()(STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) * p) const
    {
        sk_GENERAL_NAME_free(p);
    }
};

template<>
struct Deleter<GENERAL_NAME>
{
    void operator()(GENERAL_NAME* p) const
    {
        GENERAL_NAME_free(p);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename D = Deleter<T>>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> wrapUnique(T* p, D deleter = {})
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>{p, deleter};
}
}
```

And I use other helper functions to make use OpenSSL more C++sy.
This is especially handy when handling errors (since release of resources is painless in such case).

Answer (score 3):

The default deleter is ok if doing `delete` over the pointer wrapped by `unique_ptr` is the correct thing to do to dispose of it. That is ok if your pointer comes from `new`, but it's not correct in many other situations.

A simple example is `FILE *`: a `FILE *` is a pointer that cannot be deleted with `delete`, but instead you have to use `fclose` on it. Using a custom deleter it's very easy to wrap it in a `unique_ptr` and let it take care of destruction/move/...:

```
namespace detail {
    struct file_ptr_deleter {
        void operator() (FILE *fp) {
            if(fp) fclose(fp);
        }
    };
}

/// RAII-style wrapper for a FILE*
struct unique_c_file : std::unique_ptr<FILE, detail::file_ptr_deleter> {
    using std::unique_ptr<FILE, detail::file_ptr_deleter>::unique_ptr;
    operator FILE *() { return get(); }
};
```

(in this case I even inherited from `std::unique_ptr` to ease the use of `unique_c_file` directly in C APIs).

Other, possibly more common cases, are if you have memory that comes from libraries, that provide their own function to delete it; for example, you may use BSD sockets, where `getaddrinfo` provides you an `addrinfo *` that must be freed using `freeaddrinfo`; even in this case, it's easy to create a smart pointer for that:

```
namespace detail {
    struct addrinfo_deleter {
        void operator()(addrinfo *elem) {
            if(elem) freeaddrinfo(elem);
        }
    };
}

/// unique_ptr to handle an %addrinfo linked list provided by %getaddrinfo
typedef std::unique_ptr<addrinfo, detail::addrinfo_deleter> addrinfo_ptr;
```

Similarly in Win32 programming where many APIs provide you memory that has been allocated with `LocalAlloc` and thus must be freed with `LocalFree`:

```
    // Custom deleter (for unique_ptr) using Win32 LocalFree
    struct LocalFree_deleter { void operator()(void *ptr) { LocalFree(ptr); } };
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<LPWSTR[], LocalFree_deleter> argvw(CommandLineToArgvW(cmdline_u16, &argc));
```

---

You can even go a step further, and work with stuff that aren't even pointers, but opaque "handles": again in Win32 this is quite common, and there are even different types of handles require different closing functions; even in this case, `unique_ptr` and custom deleters to the rescue:

```
template<decltype(CloseHandle) ch_fn = CloseHandle>
struct handle_deleter {
    typedef HANDLE pointer;
    void operator()(HANDLE obj) {
        if(obj != NULL && obj != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ch_fn(obj);
    }
};

using unique_handle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, handle_deleter<>>;
using unique_find_handle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, handle_deleter<FindClose>>;
```

notice that here `handle_deleter` provided a `typedef HANDLE pointer`: this `typedef` is used by `unique_ptr` as the type that it stores in its bowels, returns in `get()` & co.