# How can I wrap a C object in a custom RAII Class in C++?

Tags: c++, raii

I am using the library igraph and the library uses a lot of allocating and freeing memory using custom functions. I want to remove the possibility of forgetting to free memory by using RAII.

The code beforehand looks something like this:

```cpp
void doSomething() {
   igraph_vector_t shortest_path;

   igraph_get_shortest_path_dijkstra(
      someargs...,
      &shortest_path
      someargs...
   )

   igraph_vector_destroy(&shortest_path);
};
```

I want to replace igraph_vector_t with a custom C++ class that has a destructor that calls igraph_vector_destroy so I can just do:

```
void doSomething() {
   raii_igraph_vector_t shortest_path;

   igraph_get_shortest_path_dijkstra(
      someargs...,
      &shortest_path
      someargs...
   )
}
```

I can make a custom class/struct like:

```
struct raii_igraph_vector_int {
    igraph_vector_int_t vec;
    ~RAIIVectorInt(){
        igraph_vector_int_destroy(&vec);
    }
};
```

And I can pass it into the function like:

```
   igraph_get_shortest_path_dijkstra(
      someargs...,
      &shortest_path.vec
      someargs...
   )
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to not need to add on the `.vec` and just treat it as if it were the previous type.

Comment: It's likely that you can use `std::unique_ptr` for that without writing a custom class.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The igraph documentation says to call `igraph_vector_int_destory`. It is a C library, not C++, so I dont think the memory it allocates will be destroyed when the unique pointer is destroyed, no?

Comment: @Tom McLean You can give a custom deleter to the unique_ptr

Comment: Example for OpenSSL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248210/1387438

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick (totally untested, though):

```
struct DeleteIGraphVector {
  void operator() (igraph_vector_t *vec) const {
    igraph_vector_destroy(vec);
    delete vec;
  }
};

using raii_igraph_vector_t = std::unique_ptr<igraph_vector_t, DeleteIGraphVector>;

void doSomething() {
  raii_igraph_vector_t shortest_path{new igraph_vector_t};
  
  igraph_get_shortest_path_dijkstra(
    someargs...,
    shortest_path,
    someargs...
  );
}
```

It uses `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to destroy and then delete the igraph type appropriately. One disadvantage of this approach is that the `igraph_vector_t` will be heap-allocated, though. This could be avoided with `unique_resource`, which hasn't quite made it into the C++ standard yet but is available in third-party libraries.

If you don't want to write different deleters for each igraph type, you could try using templates, like this:

```
template<typename T, void (*f_del)(T *)>
struct GenericIGraphDeleter {
    void operator() (T *obj) {
        f_del(obj);
        delete obj;
    }
};

using raii_igraph_vector_t = std::unique_ptr<
    igraph_vector_t,
    GenericIGraphDeleter<igraph_vector_t, &igraph_vector_destroy>>;

using raii_igraph_vector_int_t = std::unique_ptr<
    igraph_vector_int_t,
    GenericIGraphDeleter<igraph_vector_int_t, &igraph_vector_int_destroy>>;
```

Comment: Should the custom deleter also call delete on the pointer, or will std::unique_ptr do this anyway?

Comment: @TomMcLean The custom deleter completely replaces `unique_ptr`'s default deleter, so `unique_ptr` won't call `delete` for you anymore as a result. The custom deleter has to do it (like it already does in the example code I provided).

Comment: Thanks, there are quite a lot of igraph types so I will turn it into a template class with some of the answers commented above.

Comment: @TomMcLean If your compiler supports it already, you can use non-type template parameters to pass a function pointer to the deleter template. I'll try to include that approach in an edit to my answer.